# Azure Web App should ARR Affinity be on for ASP.NET webforms?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We don't keep and data for the pages on the server (we're transitioning to pure html/js), but we do still have asp.net masterpages and runat=sever for content of the pages.  We do have multiple app servers enabled for load balance, so on the application settings should we set ARR Affinity to on?  For some rare cases we see an 'Aw Snap' page on chrome because the page doesn't load correctly.  Maybe 1/20 times.  I wonder if that is the case.

Comment: Are you using session heavily and where is session stored?

Comment: Have you checked any sort of server logs to investigate what's the cause of the errors? And to add to @AkashKava, are your sessions in-process or are you using an out-of-process session store (state server, SQL, Redis)

Comment: It seems only 1 of our qa devs can reproduce the issue.  Our .cs behind the aspx are all empty.  The chrome 'aw snap' is a browser crash though.  Everything was fine on our old non-azure servers, but sometimes we see this now.  We think maybe it's due the the javascript timing/loading.  We do use Redis

Comment: Please enables the logs and check whether there are server error logs. It will confirm whether the error is come from server or client.

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Web App should ARR Affinity be on for ASP.NET webforms?

If your webform application is stateless, you don't need to turn on ARR Affinity. Stateless means that you need to store the application/session state in a distribute place.

> For some rare cases we see an 'Aw Snap' page on chrome because the page doesn't load correctly.

The Aw Snap error is dedicated to chrome. It may not related to your Azure Web App Server. To fix the issue, you could try the steps provided by google.

[Fix "Aw, Snap!" page crashes and other page loading errors](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)